# What RSA public key encryption options are available with Expo?

Tags: react-native, rsa, expo

What RSA public key encryption libraries are available to use **with Expo**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is https://github.com/expo/ursa, but it is not ready for use with Expo as of October 11, 2019.

Also there is https://github.com/rajtatata/react-native-expo-tweet-nacl, but it does not support PKCS1.

Comment: for those who may concern: from what I understand, tweet-nacl supports public key encryption, but it uses elliptic curve, not RSA.  So, if someone needs RSA public key in Expo, the libraries provided in this answer is not elligible.

Comment: I am looking for ja library to decrypt my data (rsa-oaep encrypted) in react native expo app. Could you recommend a library?